# Why is std::rc::Rc<> not Copy?

Tags: rust, smart-pointers

Can someone explain to me why `Rc<>` is not `Copy`?

I'm writing code that uses a lot of shared pointers, and having to type `.clone()` all the time is getting on my nerves.

It seems to me that `Rc<>` should just consist of a pointer, which is a fixed size, so the type itself should be `Sized` and hence `Copy`, right?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> It seems to me that `Rc<>` should just consist of a pointer, which is a fixed size, so the type itself should be `Sized` and hence `Copy`, right?

This is not quite true. `Rc` is short for **R**eference **C**ounted. This means that the type keeps track of how many references point to the owned data. That way we can have multiple owners at the same time and safely free the data, once the reference count reaches 0.

---

But how do we keep the reference counter valid and up to date? Exactly, we have to do something whenever a new reference/owner is created and whenever a reference/owner is deleted. Specifically, we have to increase the counter in the former case and decrease it in the latter.

The counter is decreased by implementing [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html), the Rust equivalent of a destructor. This `drop()` function is executed whenever a variable goes out of scope – perfect for our goal.

But when do we do the increment? You guessed it: in `clone()`. [The `Copy` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), by definition, says that a type can be duplicated just by copying bits:

> Types that can be copied by simply copying bits (i.e. `memcpy`).

This is not true in our case, because: yes, we "just copy bits", but we also do additional work! We do need to increment our reference counter!

- [`Drop` impl of `Rc`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.32.0/src/liballoc/rc.rs#L817-L860)
- [`Clone` impl of `Rc`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.32.0/src/liballoc/rc.rs#L863-L883)

Comment: There's also the logistic argument: With a reference counted pointer, you want to be able to distinguish when you create a new pointer, or when you just give the pointer to something else. `Copy` would remove this distinction.

Answer (score 15):

A type cannot implement `Copy` if it implements `Drop` ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#when-can-my-type-not-be-copy)). Since `Rc` [does implement it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/up/src/liballoc/rc.rs.html#449-471) to decrement its reference count, it is not possible.

In addition, `Rc` is not just a pointer. It consists of a `Shared`:

```
pub struct Rc<T: ?Sized> {
    ptr: Shared<RcBox<T>>,
}
```

Which, in turn, is not only a pointer:

```
pub struct Shared<T: ?Sized> {
    pointer: NonZero<*const T>,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

`PhantomData` is needed to express the ownership of `T`:

> this marker has no consequences for variance, but is necessary for
>   dropck to understand that we logically own a `T`.
>
> For details, see:
>   https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0769-sound-generic-drop.md#phantom-data