# How to return a State value from a Rocket endpoint?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm storing data from an external service in a local cache and I want to create an endpoint to return data currently in the cache.

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

use rocket::{Route, State};
use rocket_contrib::json::Json;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Post {
    pub title: String,
    pub body: String,
}

impl Post {
    pub fn new(title: String, body: String) -> Post {
        Post { title, body }
    }
}

pub struct Cache {
    pub posts: Vec<Post>,
}

impl Cache {
    pub fn new() -> Cache {
        let mut posts = vec![
            Post::new(String::from("Article1"), String::from("Blah")),
            Post::new(String::from("Article2"), String::from("Blah")),
            Post::new(String::from("Article3"), String::from("Blah")),
            Post::new(String::from("Article4"), String::from("Blah")),
            Post::new(String::from("Article5"), String::from("Blah")),
        ];

        Cache { posts }
    }
}

#[derive(Responder)]
pub enum IndexResponder {
    #[response(status = 200)]
    Found(Json<Vec<Post>>),
    #[response(status = 404)]
    NotFound(String),
}

#[get("/")]
pub fn index(cache: State<Cache>) -> IndexResponder {
    return IndexResponder::Found(Json(cache.posts));
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/", routes![index])
        .manage(Cache::new())
        .launch();
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `rocket::State<'_, Cache>`
  --> src/main.rs:50:39
   |
50 |     return IndexResponder::Found(Json(cache.posts));
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `std::vec::Vec<Post>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

([`cargo build --verbose` output](https://pastebin.com/tMAm7Y22))

My Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "debug-project"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Varkal <mail@example.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.0"
rocket_contrib = "0.4.0"
serde = { version = "1.0.90", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.39"
```

[A very simple repository to reproduce the error](https://github.com/Varkal/debug-project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your endpoint does not own the state and thus it cannot return an owned `Vec<Post>`. Conceptually, this makes sense because if you *did* take ownership of it, then what value would be present the next time the endpoint is called?

The simplest thing you can do is clone the data:

```
#[get("/")]
pub fn index(cache: State<Cache>) -> IndexResponder {
    IndexResponder::Found(Json(cache.posts.clone()))
}
```

This will require that you implement `Clone` for `Post`, or perhaps change your state to hold something like an `Arc`.

A slightly more performant solution is to return a slice that refers to the state. This requires no cloning, but does require using the [`State::inner`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.4.1/rocket/struct.State.html#method.inner) method:

```
#[derive(Responder)]
pub enum IndexResponder<'a> {
    #[response(status = 200)]
    Found(Json<&'a [Post]>),
    #[response(status = 404)]
    NotFound(String),
}

#[get("/")]
pub fn index<'a>(cache: State<'a, Cache>) -> IndexResponder<'a> {
    IndexResponder::Found(Json(&cache.inner().posts))
}
```

See also:

- [Cannot move out of borrowed content when trying to transfer ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28258548/155423)
- [What happens when an Arc is cloned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40984932/155423)