# "expected struct `std::rc::Rc`, found reference" - how to convert?

Tags: rust

I tried to get a reference-counted `Rc<Foo>` from a hash map and put it into a different container (`Vec<Foo>`).

Thought this would work (by incrementing the reference count), but instead I got an **"expected struct `std::rc::Rc`, found reference"** error.

How do I convert an `&Rc<Foo>` to a `Rc<Foo>`?

---

More info:

```
struct Foo();
let mut foo : HashMap<usize, Rc<Foo>> = HashMap::new();
let mut bar : Vec<Rc<Foo>> = Vec::new();
foo.insert(0, Rc::new(Foo()));
if let Some(x) = foo.get(&0) {
    bar.push(x); // expected struct `std::rc::Rc`, found reference
                 // note: expected type `std::rc::Rc<Foo>`
                 //          found type `&std::rc::Rc<Foo>`  rustc(E0308)
}
```

I get that the hash map returns a *reference* to the value it owns. But dereferencing it doesn't work: both `if let Some(&x)` and `bar.push(*x);` result in a **"cannot move out of borrowed content"**.

Curiously, adding a type annotation changes the error to **"cannot move out of an `Rc`"**:

```
    let x : &Rc<Foo> = x;
    bar.push(*x); // cannot move out of an `Rc`  rustc(E0507)
```

I need to store a reference to the same object, and not to a copy, so I avoided the `.clone()` "escape hatch".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014703/why-is-stdrcrc-not-copy ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984932/what-happens-when-an-arc-is-cloned ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To convert an `&Rc<Foo>` -> `Rc<Foo>`, use [`Rc::clone()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html#cloning-references), which gives you an Rc object of your own, increasing the reference count under the hood:

```
let ref_to_rc: &Rc<Foo> = &Rc::new(Foo());
let new_rc: Rc<Foo> = Rc::clone(ref_to_rc);
```

*`rc.clone()` is equivalent to `Rc::clone(&rc)`, but idiomatic Rust uses the latter to make it clear that the code only increases the refcount, not performing a deep copy of the data like some other implementations of `.clone()` do. ([Though in some scenarios involving traits you might need to revert to `ref_to_rc.clone()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/2048).)*

The errors above were about Rust refusing to do the copy implicitly. [Why is std::rc::Rc<> not Copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40014703/1026) has an explanation of why it behaves like that.